# SharePoint Page Title Does Not Change

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, sitepages

So I have created a bunch of SharePoint site pages where the title is just the SiteName.aspx in the Web Browser's title bar.

By default, the SharePoint title also appears in the top left of the SharePoint page which I removed with the following CSS styling:

```
.ms-core-pageTitle {
    display: none;
}
```

This removes that ugly SharePoint title from the page so I can create a better heading with CSS and HTML. Could this styling be an issue preventing the Web Browser title bar from accepting the new title?

I tried changing the title in the page settings as well and it doesn't update.

Comment: Did you try renaming the page name from Site pages? If you rename the page it will change the page URL as well.

Comment: I am guessing you are using classic experience, right?

Comment: I am using classic experience. I did not touch the page name at all because I am aware that it changes the location in the url. I tried changing the page title in page properties, and it says it updates but it doesnt.

Comment: By changing Title property it will not effect for classic pages. Did you try the solution given in my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the page title using CSS it will not effect the page title in browser's tab.

Page title which is shown in browser's tab is stored under `<title>` tag of page.

If you want to change it using code then you can use this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText = "New Site Page Name"
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked like a charm. If you could check out my most recent asked question, if you know anything about it that would be helpful as well